# Redirect MVC URL to login page if user has not login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to redirect the MVC URL to Login page if the user has not Login. The code below in web.config works well with WebForm URL, but not for MVC URL.

```
   <location path="/Home/Index">
   <system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users = "?"/>
  </authorization>
  </system.web  
    </location>

    <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name="MySite" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" protection="All"  timeout="30" path="/" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true"  cookieless="UseCookies"/>
     </authentication>
     <authorization>
     <allow users="?"/>
   </authorization>
    </system.web>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms defaultUrl="/Booking/Index" loginUrl="/Login/Index" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="2880"></forms>
</authentication>
```

Comment: How do you deny users the URL? That is my major issue

Comment: Make use of Authorize attribute on controllers/action you want to restrict access to anonymous users

Answer (score 0):

You can use this configure

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Login/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
```

or you can use [Authorize] attribute on your controller/action.

Comment: How do you deny users the URL with your first option. My approach using `Location Path` did not work for me